# "Failed to download ‘melpa’ archive" when I run package-refresh-contents

Tags: package, package-repositories

Have started seeing this error after I installed a new version of Emacs. My package code in init file is

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize)
```

This also fails if I use https. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: This looks correct. Is it still not working? It could be a temporary network issue.

Comment: Yeah still happening.

Comment: Can you open the page "http://melpa.org/packages/" in your web browser? This is strange.

Comment: Yes, I can open it in my browser. `package-list-packages` gives a bunch of stale links in Emacs, but if I go to Melpa directly in my browser I am able to download the tar files with the correct dates on the links.

Comment: Starting Emacs from `emacs -Q` and running your code exactly, I can get package-list-packages to work fine. What version of Emacs are your running? Do you have any other config in your init file? If you do, can you try running just the code you have here? Maybe there's something else in your init that's interacting.

Comment: When I do -Q `gnu` also fails as well as `melpa`. The error is `Failed to verify signature archive-contents.sig`

Comment: what version of Emacs are you running?

Comment: Does [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60560/error-retrieving-https-elpa-gnu-org-packages-archive-contents-error-http-400) help at all?

Comment: I just reinstalled 27.2.2 and it is working now?  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Emacs 27.2.2 fixed this. I am not sure why it is working now and did not work before.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Emacs 27.1 has a bug with authenticated proxies.

Comment: Nope, not behind a proxy

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to follow the `MELPA` [Getting started](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started) instructions precisely and then read `Known Issues` sections.

I got the error message "Failed to download ‘MELPA’ archive" on an earlier version of `Emacs`. In my case, it was fixed at that time by applying described in the `Known Issues` configuration:

```el
(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")
```