# Error retrieving: https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/archive-contents

Tags: osx, package-repositories

This is with the latest Emacs Version 27.2 (9.0) for Mac OS X:

```
error in process sentinel: Error retrieving: https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/archive-contents (error connection-failed "connect" :host "elpa.gnu.org" :service 443) [2 times]
```

I can access that address in a web browser fine.

My `.emacs` file contains a basic package configuration:

```
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)
```

I see others have this issue, but it's a very different issue, the answers suggest this was fixed in Emacs 27+, which I'm already using.

[Error retrieving: https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/archive-contents (error http 400)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60560/error-retrieving-https-elpa-gnu-org-packages-archive-contents-error-http-400)

Comment: It may be a temporary network glitch. What happens if you wait a few minutes and try again?

Comment: I deleted ~/.emacs.d, did a full reinstall of the latest Emacs for Mac OS X, waited several hours, and I consistently get the exact same error. I can also reliably load that web address in a web browser. I have a very good Internet connection.

Comment: @clay I have the same problem; it's not just you.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, I've downgraded from Emacs 27.2.2 to 27.1.1 and things are now working fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me, a fix is:

```
(when (equal emacs-version "27.2")
  (setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3"))
```

I found this at [Error retrieving: https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/archive-contents (error http 400)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60560/error-retrieving-https-elpa-gnu-org-packages-archive-contents-error-http-400#comment105217_62321)

EDIT:

The problem is only on some platforms, so I've changed that to:

```
(when (and (equal emacs-version "27.2")
           (eql system-type 'darwin))
  (setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3"))
```